# Issues while Invoking Python process using java process builder

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

I am using java process builder to start python process with one flag and with one argument as shown below. But i don't see any exception nor process starts up.

Command i want to run  is

```
python oc_db5.py -c input.json
```

location of file oc_db5.py is

```
/opt/jvision/grpc/gui
```

My code is shown below

```
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(

            Arrays.asList(
                    "python",
                    "oc_db5.py",
                    "-c",
                    "input.json"));

    processBuilder.directory(new File("/opt/jvision/grpc/gui"));

    processBuilder.start();

    logger.info("Process started ..." + new Date());

    int count = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()));

    while ((lineData = br.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println("line: " + ++count + " " + lineData);
        logger.info("line: " + ++count + " " + lineData);
    }
    process.waitFor();
    process.getErrorStream();
    process.waitFor();

    process.exitValue();
```

I can see that log file contains entry "process start..." but i don't really see that process is started. Wondering what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if python is in your PATH? I have similar problem with custom command long long time ago. You can use absolute path to try it :).
You can also check you enviromental variables via

> Map env = System.getenv();

If you are using Linux you can start process like "sleep 1000" then check it is present in system process table via "ps aux | grep sleep" or something like it :)